# how to display month name in jsp page from mysql database

Tags: java, jsp

i want to display values monthly wise from database. here are my fetchning code

```
<%
int i=1;
String country=request.getParameter("country");
Connection con=Singleton.getMySqlConnection();
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select MONTHNAME(start_date),Extract(year from start_date),Extract(day from start_date),event_name,state,country from conf_events where country='"+country+"' and type='approved' order by Extract(month from start_date),Extract(day from start_date) ");
%>
```

and i'm displaying  in jsp page like

```
<%while(rs.next()){%>  

      <div class="alertbox">
      <table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  >
  <tr valign="top"  >      
    <th align="left"class="alertmonth" >
    <%=rs.getString(1)%>-<%=rs.getString(2)%>
    </th>        
   </tr>



      <tr >
      <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin-top:5px;" id="cnflist">
      <tr>
      <td width="20%"><%=rs.getString(3)%>&nbsp;th</td>
      <td width="60%"><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
      <td width="20%"><%=rs.getString(5)%>,&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=rs.getString(6)%></td>      
      </tr>
```

but here middle one month is missing remaining results is displaying under the previous month,for example if **may** month is missing, next **June** and after months results coming under **April** month. i want to display the details monthly wise, if middle one(or) two months are missing display after available month details monthly wise.
give me suggestion to solve this

Comment: Let me be honest with you: this is one horribly written JSP!

Comment: Try to use `jstl` and `el` .It will be better

Comment: The most beautiful piece of code I've ever seen (sarcastic )

Comment: i'm new jsp that's y i'm trying these much code..

Comment: To be fair, JSP does not make it easy to write nice code. It supports embedded Java which IMO should NEVER be done.

Answer (score 1):

Java can give you the name of the month, given a Date.
First, select the whole Date from the database (don't just extract parts from it) and process it in Java.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

a very small and basic example:

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Date" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show Date</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String today = sdf.format(date);
%>

Today is <%=today %> 
</body>
</html>
```

Patrick